# SPF through any relay

Tags: email, spf

I'm using PHP mail() to send an email from my server to two different accounts, one which is my Gmail account, which SPF passes with, and one to an account hosted by my domain provider, which is then forwarded to my Gmail account. That causes SPF to fail because the originating IP is different.

But, there's no way to tell if the email address you send emails to is the recipient, or forwards them elsewhere. So is there any way to allow SPF to pass through any (unknown) relay?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you mean here. Are you using arbitrary From addresses?

Generally, SPF control over email sources is handled in a few different ways:

1. Authorise your domain provider's servers to send from your domain (i.e. add them to your SPF record)
2. Hope that your hosting provider's mail servers support SRS, the [Sender Rewriting Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme), which they should
3. Allow any IP to be a source of email for your domain by adding `+all` to your SPF record (clearly a bad idea!)

Comment: I want the From address to be server@mydomain.co.uk no matter what goes on in between. I just want the SPF to pass, regardless whether the email is forwarded or not, through any unknown relay, or any number of relays. As long as it's actually originating from my server, I want it to pass when it reaches the intended recipient.

Comment: That's effectively saying you don't want SPF at all. You've not said what it is doing to your message that makes it fail - can you show the headers and your sending code? When you send a message, you provide an envelope sender, which becomes the return path that SPF checks on the receiver.

Comment: spf=fail (google.com: domain of server@mydomain.co.uk does not designate 79.170.44.61 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=server@mydomain.co.uk. The sending code is just mail($to, $subject, $message)

Comment: Can you not add that IP to your SPF record?

Comment: Hence "unknown". I don't know if emails are going to be forwarded before they reach a final mailbox so the IP address could be anything.

Let's say I'm sending emails from a@b.com, to c@d.com. However, c@d.com is actually forwarding to e@f.com, so when e@f.com reads it, the SPF fails, but why? It's being sent from the right place. And I don't know whether c@d.com is forwarding, or if it's the final recipient. I just want to be able to send an email, and wherever it ends up, for SPF to still pass because I did indeed send it.

Comment: Relaying/forwarding doesn't necessarily mean that, and SRS takes care of rewriting without breaking SPF anyway. From what I can tell you're using your hosting provider's mail server, and if they know what they are doing, they will publish their own SPF that will cover all their IPs that you can `include` in your own; you only need to care about originating servers - SRS takes care of the rest without you doing anything.